# Consultas en varias tablas solo una columna, FK, PK

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Para la consulta por ejemplo de la actividad en la tabla calendario, lo podemos hacer tambien en la tabla Participante no? al estar arrastrando desde calendario a actividad y despues participante

Comment: 1. Un consulta: `Calendario -> Actividades -> Participantes` es posible. 2. Una consulta `Calendario - > Participantes` directamente no es posible. 3. Una consulta `Calendario -> Equipos -> Participantes` es posible. 4. Una consulta `Actividades - > Participantes` es posible. ¿Te refieres a 1, 2, 3, 4 ó a ninguna de las anteriores? Si es **ninguna**, explícate mejor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es muy clara la pregunta, pero si te refieres a que si es posible omitir la junta de la tabla `Actividades` pues solo bastaría con:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Calendario 
INNER JOIN Participantes 
ON Actividad=ParticipanteActividad;
```

Puesto que tanto `Calendario` como `Participantes` están relacionados a través de la `Actividad`.